# Focus Window while in a game without minimizing the game

Tags: java, swing, window, focus

there is a way of bringing my window to the front without minimizing the current Full Screen Game?

For example: I'm Playing a game and then i click CTRL+F and a window popup while I am in the game, and I can use that window and the game will not minimize or get out of focus.

I already have my code to `myFrame.toFront(); myFrame.repaint();` when I click CTRL+F.

I appreciate if someone could help me, thanks

Carlos Barros

**EDIT:** Maybe I should have said this but the game is a game like Counter Strike or League of Legends I didn't make the game.

Comment: Have you tried : `myFrame.toFront(); myFrame.repaint(); gameFrame.requestFocus()` ?

Comment: may be u can use a JDialog for a pop up..

Comment: I will try this. I think it works, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Maybe I should have said this but the game is a game like Counter Strike or League of Legends I didn't make the game.

Comment: You can use, like already said, the [JDialog(Dialog owner, String title, boolean modal)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog(java.awt.Dialog,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)), the last boolean part will be `false` for your case, else if `true` then it will bring focus to this `JDialog`.  In future, please give extra care while posting questions, your question mark is making no sense, since your question is not a question, its more like a sentence :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, its my first post. Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I already have my code to myFrame.toFront(); myFrame.repaint();

Don't use a JFrame as a popup window. An application should only have a single JFrame. For child windows you should use a JDialog. In your case it seems like you want a non-modal dialog.

> and I can use that window and the game will not minimize or get out of focus.

When you display a dialog by default it will get focus whether it is modal or not (so the frame will lose focus).

If you want to prevent a non-modal dialog from getting initial focus then you need code like the following:

```
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( false );
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setFocusableWindowState( true );
```

When you make the dialog visible it will not get focus (and the frame will retain focus). However, if you later click on the dialog it will be able to gain focus.